# Using Node Rollup how do I generate ES2015 output

Tags: ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I have 2 JS files which i want to bundle them in one so I can upload it to a 3rd party system and still have common fns available outside for reuse.
The 3rd party system needs the code to be in ES2015 and give me error with bundled file 
error: `Compilation failed: Unexpected token import`

app.js

```
const { AuthenticationClient } = require('auth0');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Express = require('express');
// some more stuff here
exports.app = app;
```

index.js
    `import { app } from './app.js';`

When I run rollup op file looks like

```
    import auth0 from 'auth0';
    import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
    import express from 'express';
    import requestPromise from 'request-promise';
    // stuff
```

rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
export default [
    {
        input: 'webtask/forgot-password/index.js',
        output: {
            format: 'es',
        },
        external: ['auth0', 'body-parser', 'express', 'request-promise', 'webtask-tools'],

        plugins: [
            commonjs({
                namedExports: { './webtask/forgot-password/app.js': ['named' ] }  
            })
        ]
    }
];
```

Is this possible? Should i go back to older version of rollup?

Answer (score 0):

Use `format: 'cjs'`. `es` (which is actually deprecated in favour of `esm`) is for a) libraries that are going to be bundled themselves, and b) browsers that can load modules natively.